# Проверка ключей:значений двух JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Есть 2 JSON файла, один основной, там есть {id:1} и второй, где есть {subId:1}. Как связать два этих JSON, чтобы отрисовать из них данные(1-ый это основной товар, а 2-ой всякие допы). Загвоздка ещё в том, что значения не уникальные, может быть {count:1} например. То есть надо как-то по ключам сравнивать.
Ниже пример.

```json
{
"Value": {
    "Params": [
      { "Cost": 158, "GroupID": 1, "Quantity": 1, "ID": 1 },
      { "Cost": 222, "GroupID": 2, "Quantity": 1, "ID": 4 }
    ]
  }
}
{
    "1": {
        "Group": "Товары",
        "Units": {
            "1": {
                "Name": "Товар 1",
            }
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "Group": "Товары 2",
        "Units": {
            "4": {
                "Name": "Товар 2",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Приложите пример ваших json'ов, только не полный листинг, так будет проще дать более точный ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Добавил пример в вопрос.

Comment: У вас тут `{ "Cost": 222, "GroupID": 2, "Quantity": 1, "ID": 4 }`, поле `ID` должно пересекаться с ключом из вложенного объекта `Units`?

Comment: Да, а GroupID с 1-ым ключом.

Comment: Я обновил свой ответ ниже, должно вам помочь.

Comment: Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашей задачи вам нужно замапить два json'а в нужную вам структуру, сделать это можно следующим образом (скрипт написан в моем видении структуры, вы можете на основе него собрать уже свою, главное, чтобы в общем смысле было понятно, что там происходит):

```js
const generateGoodsCart = (groups, adds) => Object
  .keys(adds) // извлекаем ключи (названия дополнений)
  .reduce((acc, addsName) => {
    const { Params } = adds[addsName];

    Params.forEach((param) => {
      const { [param.GroupID]: group } = groups; // извлекаем группу
      if (!group) return;

      if (!acc[param.GroupID]) {
        // если в генерируемой модели отсутствует группа
        // то добавляем данную структуру
        acc[param.GroupID] = {
          groupId: param.GroupID,
          groupName: group.Group,
          additionals: [],
        };
      }

      const { Units: { [param.ID]: unit } } = group; // извлекаем юнит
      if (!unit) return;

      // добавляем структуру дополнений к товару
      acc[param.GroupID].additionals.push({
        unitId: param.ID,
        unitName: unit.Name,
        cost: param.Cost,
        quantity: param.Quantity,
      });
    });

    return acc;
  }, {});

const goodsCart = generateGoodsCart(groups, adds);
```

Мы получим такую структуру (в примере только часть полученных данных):

```js
{
  1: {
    groupId: 1,
    groupName: 'Товары',
    additionals: [
      {
        cost: 222,
        quantity: 1,
        unitId: 4,
        unitName: 'Товар 2',
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

Так же, так как мы сохраняем `groupId` в нашей структуре, мы можем извлечь только массив (будет удобнее использовать в итерациях) нужных нам значений при помощи [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
const goodsCart = Object.values(generateGoodsCart(groups, adds));
```

Comment: А как в одну структуру всё завернуть или как связи установить-то? В принципе в этом и был мой вопрос=)

Comment: Там в коде используется forEach на объекте, это же не возможно или я чего-то не понимаю? Четвёртая и пятая строчка.

Comment: Посмотрите пример json’а внимательно, там поле Params - это массив.

Comment: А мы разве там не объявляем новый объект с именем Params и передаём в него объект из дополений?

Comment: Нет, там происходит [деструктуризация](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring), данная строка равносильна следующей: const Params = adds[addsName].Params

Comment: Спасибо, теперь я понял, как оно там работает. Только теперь другая проблема, Params всегда равен undefined. Если я всё же правильно понял, то это из-за того, что во втором json файле у меня нет ключа Params, а судя по данной записи оно подразумевает его наличие?

Comment: Нет, не подразумевает, я запускал данный скрипт с вашими сэмплами json’ов, первый аргумент группы, второй дополнения.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Значит проблема в том, как я получаю json наверное.

Comment: Вы можете собрать сниппет кода например на jsfiddle или типа того,  с примером входных данных с сервера (маленьким куском) и этим кодом для запуска, потому что пока проблема очень абстрактная.

Comment: Я буквально использую всё то же самое, что написал выше и ваш код. Я ручками написал объект равный по структуре, как мой json, через JSON.parse() оно тоже не отрабатывает.
https://jsfiddle.net/TomatoBrain/xd3Lybwk/4/

Comment: Вы первым аргументом передаете дополнения, а вторым группы, там же по коду видно. Аргументы у себя в пример в фидле местами поменяйте.

Comment: Господи, у меня в голове это было наоборот. Первое - это основной, а второе - дополнения. Однако с реальными данными я пытался менять их местами и всё равно не отрабатывало, но буду смотреть уже там. Больше не буду вас мучать, спасибо огромное за помощь.

Comment: Разобрался, у меня 1-ый json  приходит не только с Value, но перед ними есть ещё ключи. Правда пока не знаю, что с эти делать.

Comment: Ну если вы поняли, как работает скрипт, то просто чуть его доработать.